# How do I update an annotation without using setCoordinate?

Tags: cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mkannotation, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a subclassed NSManagedObject that conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol and it has NSNumber properties for latitude and longitude.

When I change any coordinates myself, I use setCoordinate: and update the latitude and longitude properties inside the implementation of setCoordinate:. Using this method, the map view updates the annotations. However, when I merge changes with another NSManagedObjectContext via mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:, setCoordinate: is not used because the latitude and longitude properties are explicitly changed. This prevents any KVO notifications going out about the coordinate changing.

I have tried to get the map view to realize the coordinate depends on the latitude and longitude properties with this code:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSSet *keyPaths = [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];

    if ([@"coordinate" isEqualToString:key]) {
        NSSet *affectingKeys = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"latitude", @"longitude", nil];
        keyPaths = [keyPaths setByAddingObjectsFromSet:affectingKeys];
    }

    return keyPaths;
}
```

However that code produces this crash:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer  for the key path "coordinate" from  because it is not registered as an observer.'**

Any ideas on how to prevent that crash or alternative methods to get the coordinate KVO notification sent out when the latitude or longitude is changed? Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by changing `setCoordinate:` so that it uses the [primitive accessors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW5) that are automatically generated by Core Data to set the `latitude` and `longitude` properties.

I suspect that because my `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:` made the `coordinate` key dependent on both the `latitude` and `longitude` keys, the `MKMapView` was getting confused when `setCoordinate:` used the public accessors instead of the primitive accessors.

When the public accessor methods were used to set the latitude and longitude, any object observing the `coordinate` key path observed three separate changes (for the key paths `coordinate`, `latitude`, and `longitude`) when there was only one change (`coordinate`) that should be observed, which confused the map view.

Comment: Also I'd like to note that, because `coordinate` is not a modeled property in my `NSManagedObject`, I had to return `NO` for `+ (BOOL)contextShouldIgnoreUnmodeledPropertyChanges`. Without that, the `NSManagedObjectContext` wasn't saving the changes since I am using primitive accessors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little overhead, but you could observe the `latitude` and `longitude` params (resp. override their setters), and force-set the coordinate (with `setCoordinate:`) when the change.

Comment: I don't mind the overhead, but my `setCoordinate:` method uses `setLatitude:` and `setLongitude:`, so it would make an infinite loop.